# Get the file capabilities of a file in Linux Android

Tags: android, linux, file, linux-capabilities

I am wondering how it's possible to get the granted capabilities for a file on the Android file system.
libcap is not available for me, therefore, I can't use its functionalities to fetch this.

Is there any other option?

Comment: I did this by cross-compiling libcap and getcap tool. Yes annoying, yes I hate how this isn't a part of ls or lsattr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [termux app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)

Run app and then install libcap. Libcap will installed locally for termux:

```
$ pkg install libcap -y
...
```

lets check it on Android 7.1.1

```
$ getcap /system/bin/run-as
/system/bin/run-as = cap_setgid, cap_setuid+ep
```

Comment: Its "getcap" instead of "getcat"